# Provide network data from Firebug to Python

Tags: python, firebug, clipboard

Is there a way to copy the network data from Firebug (for example POST headers) and put them into Python code so I don't need to write each header by myself?

There is an option *Copy Request Headers*, but it is not in the right format for Python.

So the thing I want is not to obtain this:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

because I have to change the format to dictionary or something else, but this:

```
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
```

It is not necessary to get it in Python's dictionary format. The only thing I want is to automatically use this data in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post-process the headers you've copied from Firefox: split each line of the input string by `:` and make a dictionary, example:

```
In [1]: headers = """
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
"""

In [2]: dict(item.split(": ", 1) for item in headers.splitlines() if item)
Out[2]: 
{'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0'}
```

Comment: It seems ok but it returns an error.     dictionary = dict(item.split(": ", 1) for item in headers.splitlines() if item)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: firebug_headers_to_dict("""
POST /Tournaments.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: data.skga.sk
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: cs,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://data.skga.sk/Tournaments.aspx
Cookie: __utma=90264207.2070959350.1431268267.1431268267.1431273199.2; __utmz=90264207.1431273199.2.2.utmcsr=skga.sk|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/turnaje.php; ASP.NET_SessionId=q2bahxy0wuaxaa55j52cmdmf; __utmc=90264207
""")

Comment: @Milan from what I understand, you can just skip the first line: `dict(item.split(": ", 1) for item in headers.splitlines()[1:] if item)`